# How to call a Vimscript function that has a range using local variables, from within another function?

Tags: vim, boilerplate

Here is an example that I am working with. It is intended to add a boilerplate to a file, and then comment out those lines using Vim `BlockComment()` plugin function. The goal is to mark the line number before I read from the file and after I have completed reading from the file, so that I can comment out the range of lines just inserted.

However, I am having a time figuring out what the syntax should be to indicate that range. The commented line below is my attempt to call a function with a given range using variables. The commented part has a syntax error, but, if I provide a hard-coded range as shown below, the script works. How do we put my range in as a variable in this case?

```
function! AddBoilerPlate()
    let s:beginLine = line(".")
    r /Users/danieljbrieckjr/myBolierPlate.txt
    exe "normal! joDate Created: " . strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    exe "normal! oLast Modified: " . strftime("%B %d, %Y")

    let s:endLine = line(".")

"--------------------------------------------------
"     s:beginLine, s:endLine call Comment()
"-------------------------------------------------- 

    1,3 call Comment()

endfunction
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One can prepare a string containing the target command,
and then use `:execute` to run it:

```
:exec s:beginLine..','..s:endLine 'call Comment()'
```

Comment: What if you need the return value of Comment()?

Comment: @StephenTalley: As far as I know, it is not possible. The simplest workaround is to create a helper function that takes the range line numbers as regular arguments, and call that the regular way.